# Take the interval values of vector in R

Tags: r, vector

I have a `numeric` vector as follows.

```
w <- c(75.0, 64.0, 47.4, 66.9, 62.2, 62.2, 58.7, 63.5, 66.6, 64.0, 57.0, 69.0, 56.9, 50.0, 72.0)
```

And, I want to take the values between **50~60**. What i've done so far is:

```
w[w<60] 
w[w>50]
```

Lastly ,this one was unexpected :

```
w[50<w<60]
```

Comment: You need `w[w>50 & w<60]`.

Comment: thank you! sorry for my basic problem.it works.

Comment: @Kevin - on the flipside, you can do such comparisons in SAS, and it always confused me!

Comment: @Pascal Consider to post as a solution and close this.